# Multi-Org Connector syncing Salesforce CRM to multiple Salesforce Marketing Cloud Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

We are integrating one instance of Salesforce CRM to multiple BUs in Marketing Cloud. We are going to be syncing data only in the parent BUs and will use the sync in child BUs for the purpose of Journey Builder Activities. We are using the System Admin user in CRM for the integration with Parent BU. Is it okay to sync the child BUs will a custom profile with permission sets for child BUs? Or should we be using the System admin user for all syncs?

Comment: Any particular reason for using multi-org? Default single-org connector does also support triggering journeys in child BUs, even though the synced data extensions are only pushed to the ENT BU.

Answer (score 1):

System Administrator Profile for the Salesforce System User is recommended, regardless of if it is used in the Parent BU or the Child BU. If you do use a Custom Profile and see issues with visibility, then you should probably make the switch to System Administrator.

Just as a note, make sure to utilize different System Users for each BU if you don't want the same objects synced in all the BUs connected to the same Org. Please refer to the documentation below:

[Utilizing Different Synchronized Objects from SFDC in Business Units integrated with the same Salesforce Org via Multi-Org Connector](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000353956&type=1)